# Laravel Eloquent relationship (3 tables)

Tags: model, controller, laravel-blade, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 tables in a database
1.Volume:id,volume,number,...
2.Papers:id,volume_id,title,...
3.Editor_name:id,idP(Papers ID),name...
The 'Papers' table has column 'volume_id' coming from 'Volume' and 'Editor_name' has 'idP'  column which connected to 'Papers' table column 'id'.

I don't know which method to use(hasMany or hasManyThrough) and  how to define functions in the controller (VolumeController).
I have 3 model (Volume,Papers,Names)
**Volume model** :

```
  public function names()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Names::class, Papers::class,'volume_id','idP','id','id',);
}
```

or:
**Volume model** :

```
public function papers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Papers::class,'volume_id');
}
```

**Papers model** :

```
public function volume()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Volume::class,'volume_id');
}
public function names()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EditorName::class,'idP');
}
```

**Names model** :

```
  public function papers()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Papers::class,'idP');
}
```

And what I want:
URI /volume/1/1
**Volume 1  Number 1**
Title 1
Editor 1 Editor 2 Editor 3
Title 2
Editor 4 Editor 5
Title 3
Editor 6 Editor 7  Editor 8 ...
URI /volume/1/2
**Volume 1 Number 2**
Title 4
Editor 9 Editor 10 Editor 11
Title 5
Editor 12

**VolumeController**

```
 public function papers($id){
    $papers = Papers::all()->where('volume_id',$id);      
    return view('volume_ID',compact('papers'));

}
```

Comment: You want to achieve all `Editor_name` from `Volume` model?

Comment: only Editor_name->name

Comment: Then you need `hasManyThrough()`, i checked it. Dont find any mistake. What the error you get?

Comment: I don't know how to define controller and blade.

Comment: Like this way `$volume = Volume::with('names')->get();`

Comment: but i need this data ({{table->column}}):  {{volume->id}} {{papers->title}} by volume_id   {{Editor_name->name}} by idP.

Comment: Please tell me more details, so I can help

Comment: I need to select Volume by ID, then display title from table Papers by volume_id and then i need to display name from table editor_name by idP(papers.id). For example volume.id = 1 has many titles (secondary key volume_id) in table papers and  each title has many names from table Editor_name (secondary key idP). I need to display these datas in one blade.

Comment: I hope you got your solution on the answer :)

Comment: yes, thank you  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volume Model :

```php
public function names()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Names::class, Papers::class,'volume_id','idP','id','id',);
}

public function papers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Papers::class,'volume_id');
}
```

In controller :

```php
$id = 1;
$q = Volume::with('names', 'papers')->findOrFail($id);
```

Blade :

```php
Volume : {{ $q->volume }}
Number : {{ $q->number }}

@foreach($q->papers as $paper)
   Paper Title : {{ $paper->title }}
@endforeach

@foreach($q->names as $name)
   Name : {{ $name->name }}
@endforeach
```